# The Right Way? Including JS in both NodeJS and HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I have a object that is used for passing message from client to server.

```
var JSONMessage = function() {
    this.sender = "";
    this.method = "";
    this.arguments = "";
}
```

I want this object to be available both to the server (NodeJS) as well as the client (HTML).  Currently I am doing the following below the above object.

```
if ( typeof module === 'undefined' ) {
    console.log("must be client side!");
}
else {
    module.exports = JSONMessage;
}
```

And in the nodeJS file I do the following

```
var JSONMessage = require('./public/js/message');
```

While in the HTML I can simply include the js file.

My question is, is this the best way sharing code between Node and Javascript?

Comment: check out http://socket.io/. You use that to send objects between clients and servers

Comment: There is no such thing as "the best way". One way may be the simplest, another the fastest, another takes the least resources, etc. The way to do it really depends on what you plan to do *overall*. For a one-off situation, doing it the way you are doing is not a big deal but if you want to do this with multiple files and want modularity, then there are better options, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html), which can be used both server-side and browser-side. I believe Browserify (which I've never used) can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the umdjs patterns hosted in this Github Repo:

https://github.com/umdjs/umd

What you are doing will work, but you can eliminate the guess work by using one from that repo.